# How can I compress screenshot to send it via net?

Tags: c#, compression, screenshot, jpeg

My app make screenshot using methods from WinAPI. Screen is ok, it is saved as gif and has 76 kB. Jpg, png and other formats have more size. I have to send this file via net and it takes several seconds, about 2-3 seconds. It is posibility to compress this file in .NET or any free external software ? Quality don't have good, because I have to read only several labels.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to scale the images (lower the resolution) before saving it? You can do that in pure C#.

Comment: 2-3 seconds to send 76kb seems a bit slow... What code are you using?

Comment: VNC is a fairly light protocol and contains many decent image transmission optimizations. Even if you don't use it in whole, you might learn a thing or two about the _right_ way to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at resizing the image in c#.  It's fairly easy to do... here's some code I've used in the past to do this:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(fi.FullName);
image = resizeImage(image, new Size(120, 120));
EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, (long)85);
ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
image.Save(OutSourceLoc + "/" + fi.Name, jpegCodec, encoderParams);


static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
    {
        int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        else
            nPercent = nPercentW;

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        b.SetResolution(300, 300);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;

        g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
        g.Dispose();

        return (Image)b;

    }

    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
    {
        // Get image codecs for all image formats 
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

        // Find the correct image codec 
        for (int i = 0; i < codecs.Length; i++)
            if (codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType)
                return codecs[i];
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the text, maybe you could reduce the colours to e.g. 4 colour grey image?

Comment: That could make the (presumed) text recognition harder, maybe.

Comment: Reducing the color depth should be done without dithering if you want png/gif compression to work well afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are trying to consolidate the transfer of several images into a single file (by combining them into a single Zip file, for example) I don't see the point of compressing the images.

JPG, GIF or PNG are already compressed almost as much as possible. Compressing an existing file using GZIP, for example, is a waste of computing resources w/o benefit.

JPG, GIF, PNG already employ compression just as mp3 does.

From Wikipedia:

> Portable Network Graphics (PNG  /ˈpɪŋ/[2]) is a bitmapped image format that employs lossless **data compression**
>
> JPEG ( /ˈdʒeɪpɛɡ/ [pronounced as jay - peg] is a commonly used method of **lossy compression** for digital photography (image)
>
> GIF images are compressed using the Lempel-Ziv-Welch (LZW) **lossless data compression** technique to reduce the file size without degrading the visual quality